# How to manually adjust index in dbf python package?

Tags: python, database, indexing, dbf

I am looking for a way to manually adjust the index when walking through dbf files using Ethan Furman's dbf package for Python. My current issue is the program that generated the original files had a bad habit of adding a row at the end of the file with all spaces for every entry.

I am trying to find a way to detect this and manually move the index back by one or two to account for this after moving the index to the end of file.

Comment: Are you wanting to add data to the first empty record, or easy access to the last non-empty record?

Comment: Easy access to the last non-empty record

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to `dbf` as empty records are unusual.  A bit of custom code should solve the problem, though:

```
def is_empty_rec(rec):
    # 'empty' means all fields are blank/False/0
    return any(bool(fld) for fld in rec)

def last_nonempty_index(table):
    # 'table' can also be a list
    i = len(table) - 1
    while is_empty(rec(table[i]):
        i -= 1
    return i
```